# AJAX, jQuery - if $_GET['var'] is set, how to animate one container and fade in another that loaded new content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, get, hyperlink

I have a `<table id="pickups">` in `/pages/home.php`. `index.php` does include `home.php` by default, if no other page is set. If you click an element (*logfile*) in a certain column of that table, the `.main`-container that contains the `#pickups`-table will `.animate()` to a certain size and new content is being loaded into a `.pickup`-container and will fade in right under the `.main`-container.

Now I do want to support **direct links**, so if you link to **website.tld/?pickup=name** I want the `#pickups`-table to `animate()` just like when you click one *logfile*-element in `#pickups`-table.

You can try out the example here:

1. Normal link (you have to click on a logfile): [fortress.pwnz.it](http://fortress.pwnz.it/)
2. Direct link (I want the animation to automatically happen when `$_GET['pickup']` is set, just like when you click on a *logfile* in the table's logfiles-column): [fortress.pwnz.it/?pickup=CTFCL-20130816-0132-openfire_lowgrens](http://fortress.pwnz.it/?pickup=CTFCL-20130816-0132-openfire_lowgrens)

Here is what I got so far:

**jQuery**, the code below is located within `$(document).ready(function() { <scope> })` scope.

```
    var mainIsCollapsed = 0;
    var mainLastHeight = 0;

    var $_GET = {};
    document.location.search.replace(/\??(?:([^=]+)=([^&]*)&?)/g, function() {
        function decode(s) {
            return decodeURIComponent(s.split("+").join(" "));
        }
        $_GET[decode(arguments[1])] = decode(arguments[2]);
    });
    //if direct link was clicked
    if($_GET['pickup'] != null) {
        var pickup = $_GET['pickup'];
        alert('var pickup: ' + pickup);
        loadPickup(pickup);
    }



    //if td element is clicked
    $('#pickups td:first-child').click(function() {
        loadPickup($(this).attr('name'));
    });


    //fade out content and animate 'main' to its normal size
    $('div.main').click(function() {
        if($(':animated').length)
            return false;
        if(mainIsCollapsed == 1) {
            $('div.pickup').fadeOut(250);

            $(this).animate({
                height: mainLastHeight
            }, 600, function() {
                mainIsCollapsed = 0;
            });
        }
    });




    //animate table and fade in content
    var loadPickup = function(pickup) {
        alert(pickup);

        if($(':animated').length)
                return false;

        if(mainIsCollapsed == 0) {
            mainLastHeight = $('div.main').height();

            //collapse main frame
            $('div.main').animate({
                height:'50px'                    
            }, 600, function() {
                mainIsCollapsed = 1;
            });
            //load content
            $('div.pickup').load('/pages/pickup.php?pickup=' + pickup, function() {
                //fade in
                $('div.pickup').fadeIn(300);
                //some other code here for tooltips and such
            });
    }
```

The problem is that when using the *direct link*, the function `loadPickup(pickup)` is never executed (the `alert(pickup)` message box never pops up and it seems like all jQuery scripts stop working).

**files:**

1. `index.php` loads the jQuery/javascript above
2. `index.php` includes `/pages/home.php`
3. `index.php` contains the `div.pickup` that will be displayed after new content was loaded
4. `/pages/pickup.php` is the content that is loaded into `div.pickup`
5. `/pages/home.php` contains the `.main` container (the one to be animated), within that container the `#pickups` table is located

**EDIT**

I have tried calling `loadPickup('CTFCL-20130816-0132-openfire_lowgrens');` directly in the `$(document).ready()` function, it won't call it there either. Instead all jQuery appears to stop working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is fairly simple; I'm used to programming in obj-c and Java. If I move the `loadPickup()` function to the top of the `$(document).ready()` it works. If it is defined below its call, jQuery doesn't know the function yet when it is trying to execute it.